# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column

Tags: mysql, teamcity, rake-test

I'm trying to run unit and integrations test using TeamCity.

Already configured a step which runs rake test (that include by default test load, purge etc). But all my unit tests fails with this:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'bid_for_referred_user' in 'field list': INSERT INTO`general_settings` ...

I don't know what's going on, because i set up this in another server with another version of MySQL (5.5) and most of tests passed. MySQL version is related? Here i'm using 5.0.95 on CentOS 5.7. Or just I forgot to configure something in TeamCiy?

Comment: Do you need to import something ? Database, table or something ? Basicly it say that you are missing a column named name inside the database...

Comment: But it have no sense, because it's supposed that test instruction creates a test database or empty if is already created one. I also have a 'rake db:migrate' instruction configured, but that just migrates the development database.

Comment: I already added the name of the column on the errors, and i figure out that the column created in test database is different: "bids_for_referred_user"