# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list' ruby fixtures

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, fixtures

I try to run the test but it fails as below.

```
[user1 project]$  rake test
DEPRECATION WARNING: String based terminators are deprecated, please use a lambda. (called from included at /home/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/bundler/gems/authlogic-09163c7d2a9b/lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:66)
DEPRECATION WARNING: String based terminators are deprecated, please use a lambda. (called from included at /home/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/bundler/gems/authlogic-09163c7d2a9b/lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:67)
Started

ERROR["test_login_and_access_bookmarks/managing_bookmarks", BookmarksTest, 0.120519093]
 test_login_and_access_bookmarks/managing_bookmarks#BookmarksTest (0.12s)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list': INSERT INTO `roles` (`id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (4, 2, '2015-03-15 17:54:24', '2015-03-15 17:54:24')


  1/1: [=========================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.12271s
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
[user1 project]$
```

I have two tables users and roles and two fixtures named `users.yml` and `roles.yml`.

Content of users.yml :

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html


user2:
  name: user2
  id: 2
```

Contents of roles.yml:

```
user2_1:
  id: 4
  user_id: 2
```

What could be the problem here? I am trying to link the users table with roles establishing a relationship such that - user2 from users table has role id 4 in roles table. Would appreciate any help/advice. Thanks!

I checked some stackoverflow posts like this- [ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727199/activerecordstatementinvalid-mysql2error-unknown-column) but did not find a working answer.

Structure of roles table:

```
mysql> describe roles
    -> ;
+-----------------+--------------
| Field           | Type         
+-----------------+--------------
| id              | int(11)      
| name            | varchar(255) 
| parent_id       | int(11)      
| description     | varchar(255) 
| default_page_id | int(11)      
| cache           | text         
| created_at      | datetime     
| updated_at      | datetime     
+-----------------+--------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `user_id` field in the `roles` table; most likely you are trying to specify `parent_id` here.

Best way to implement the association between users and roles in fixtures would be as follows:

```
# users.yml
user2:
  name: User 2

# roles.yml
role2:
  name: Second role
  parent: user2 (User)
```

Note: Setting `parent: user2 (User)` in `roles.yml` makes the `role2` object use `user2` as the parent, and since the object types are different (`parent` vs `user`), the `(User)` string should be included to denote the polymorphic relationship.

Please do go over the http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html page to get familiar with fixtures.